# .exd file not generated correctly by Excel when inserting activeX control

Tags: c#, excel, activex

I developed an ActiveX control in C# (Visual Studio 2012) and tried to insert it in a userform in Excel.

Things went fine, until I made the mistake of modifying the interface class of the control by adding new methods and properties. From the info I found on the net, this seems to be a mortal sin?

I can see the new methods or properties in the generated .dll and .tlb files, so that's fine. However, it seems that Excel somehow remembers the old interface and generates the .exd file accordingly. In the .exd files, the new properties and methods do not show.

I have tried a lot of things now: deleting the .exd. Does not work, as the new .exd is still generated wrongly. I also created a new project, and modified all the class names and GUID's. Does not work. I tried to delete everthing relating to the project from the registry. Does not work.
Uninstalled Visual Studio and Office, reinstalled and tried again. Did not help...

What the !!!! is going on ??? Thanks for helping me out here, as I am wasting my bloody time.

Comment: UPDATE: There seems to be a limit or so on the number of properties/methods that the Excel wrapper for the ActiveX control accepts? I have removed some unused properties such as Enable, Visible, and then I can see my latest added property and method in the .exd file, and therefore it also works in Excel VBA...

Comment: UPDATE2: the above does not work either. Although VBA does not complain any longer, the wrong C# function is invoked, so the interface is still messed up.